# chai "equals" fails on comparison?

Tags: typescript, chai, assertions

//Using chai & mocha on typescript
I'm comparing two arrays:

```
it('test my function', function () {
  let expectedResult = [ '100998', '100999' ];
  let res = myFunc();
  res.should.deep.equal(expectedResult);
})
```

but all I get is this response:

```
AssertionError: expected [ '100998', '100999' ] to equal [ '100998', '100999' ]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is `res` really a plain array?

Comment: @robertklep totally

Comment: Also, my version of Chai (3.5.0) says _"expected [...] to **deeply equal** [...]"_, but yours doesn't. Which is strange.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try using **expect** to accomplish the same thing?

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
// …
expect(res).to.deep.equal(expectedResult);
```

If that works, then there’s something wrong in how you set up `should`. Did you require it like this?

```
const should = require('chai').should(); // call the function!
```

If there’s still any problems, then we have to look at the **definition** of `myFunc()`.

*Side Note: you should only use **let** if you are going to change the variable’s value more than once. That does not seem to be the case for you, so I’d suggest you use `const` instead.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expect(res).to.be.deep.equal` like nbkhope mentioned. This worked for me too. But you should be careful with that. You sometimes lose precision by using `deep`. Why this is the case is described in [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/the-dangers-of-deep-equal-assertions-in-chai-js-f25a212f671f)